# Python - func with namedtuple that returns value based on key as func arg

Tags: python

Is it possible to put a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) collection in a function, and return values based on function arguments?

This is possible with dicts:

```
def sample_dict(key):
    a = {1 : "value1", 2 : "value2"}
    return a[key]

print(sample_dict(1)) #prints value1
```

Below I put the namedtuple in a function, but I don't know if it's possible to return values from tuple based on namedtuple keys given as function argument:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def get_namedtuple_values(key):
    UsrDetails = namedtuple('UsrDetails', 'name age programming_language')
    usr1348 = UsrDetails(name="Mike", age=28, programming_language="Python")
    return #...here should return name, age or programming_language values
```

Comment: `getattr(usr1348, key)`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, if that's the answer, please post it as an answer.

Comment: `getattr` is the better answer, yes, should post it as one.

Answer (score 0):

As originally pointed out in the comments, you can access attributes of a namedtuple instance using `getattr`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def get_namedtuple_values(key):
    UsrDetails = namedtuple('UsrDetails', 'name age programming_language')
    usr1348 = UsrDetails(name="Mike", age=28, programming_language="Python")
    return getattr(usr1348, key)

print(get_namedtuple_values("name"))
```

Result:

```
Mike
```

Answer (score -1):

A `namedtuple` has an `._asdict()` method which return a dictionary representing this object. You can use it as such:

```
def get_namedtuple_values(key):
    UsrDetails = namedtuple('UsrDetails', 'name age programming_language')
    usr1348 = UsrDetails(name="Mike", age=28, programming_language="Python")
    return usr1348._asdict()[key]
```

Note that in this case, the leading underscore for `_asdict` is meant to avoid conflict with the field names. It does not meant as a private property flag.

Comment: Although you  have to wonder what the point is of creating a namedtuple in the first place, since the values are hard-coded and the output is only a single key.

Comment: I do as a matter of principle not down-vote, but creating a dict (or OrderedDict) just to get hold of a single item does seem recklessly wasteful.